draggable container can't update content in FLET
I'm making a custom button with picture and text with a container. I made it clickable and it works fine. I can update text and image on the fly with no issues.
But I'm doing a project in which I need to make a matrix of buttons and I want swap them when I drag one over each other. So I need to make the button draggable and Drag target at the same time.In that case I'm unable to update text or image in the container. If I change text or image in a container only the feedback container is updated, but not the main container. I've made this in many different ways for three days and I have no result.
This is my code. (sorry, variables are in Spanish)
import base64
import flet as ft

class BotonPersonalizado:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Parámetros estándar
        self.tab = kwargs.get('tab', 0)
        self.fila = kwargs.get('fila', 0)
        self.columna = kwargs.get('columna', 0)
        self.ancho = kwargs.get('ancho', 250)
        self.alto = kwargs.get('alto', 100)
        self.texto = kwargs.get('texto', "Botón")
        self.foto = kwargs.get('foto', "")
        self.color = kwargs.get('color', ft.colors.BLUE_GREY_600)
        self.on_click = kwargs.get('on_click', None)
        self.on_drag_will_accept = kwargs.get('on_drag_will_accept', None)
        self.on_drag_accept = kwargs.get('on_drag_accept', None)
        self.drag_group = kwargs.get('drag_group', "matrix")
        
        # Otros parámetros dinámicos
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        
        # Inicializar el contenedor
        self.container = None
        self.content_datos = None
  
        # Crear texto e imagen dentro del contenedor
        self.imagen = ft.Image(
            src_base64=self.foto,
            width=80,
            height=80,
            fit=ft.ImageFit.COVER,
            border_radius=40
        )

        self.linea_texto = ft.Text(
            self.texto,
            width=175,
            size=18,
            weight=ft.FontWeight.W_400,
            color=ft.colors.WHITE,
            max_lines=3,
            text_align=ft.TextAlign.CENTER
        )

        self.contenedor_boton = ft.Container(
            width=250,
            height=100,
            content=ft.Row(
                controls=[
                    ft.Container(
                        content=self.imagen,  # Usa la imagen almacenada
                        padding=0,
                        margin=0
                    ),
                    self.linea_texto  # Usa el texto almacenado
                ],
                alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.START,
                spacing=1,
                width="100%",
                height="100%"
            ),
            bgcolor=ft.colors.BLUE_GREY_900,
            border_radius=20,
            margin=1,
            padding=1,
            alignment=ft.alignment.center_left,
            expand=1,
            ink=True,
            on_click=lambda e: self._handle_click(e, self.tab, self.fila, self.columna),
        )


        def dibujar_boton(self):
            return ft.DragTarget(
                group="matrix",
                content=ft.Draggable(
                    group="matrix",
                    content=self.contenedor_boton,
                    content_feedback=ft.Container(
                        width=250,
                        height=100,
                        content=ft.Row(
                            controls=[
                                ft.Container(
                                    content=self.imagen,  # Usa la imagen almacenada
                                    padding=0,
                                    margin=0
                                ),
                                self.linea_texto  # Usa el texto almacenado
                            ],
                            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.START,
                            spacing=1,
                            width="100%",
                            height="100%"
                        ),
                        bgcolor=ft.colors.BLACK54,
                        border_radius=20,
                        margin=1,
                        padding=1,
                        alignment=ft.alignment.center_left,
                        expand=1,
                    ),
                ),
                on_will_accept=lambda e: self._handle_drag_will_accept(e),
                on_accept=lambda e: self._handle_drag_accept(e)
            )



    def _handle_click(self, e):
        if self.on_click:
            self.on_click(e, self.tab, self.fila, self.columna)

    def _handle_drag_will_accept(self, e):
        if self.on_drag_will_accept:
            self.on_drag_will_accept(e, self.tab, self.fila, self.columna)

    def _handle_drag_accept(self, e):
        if self.on_drag_accept:
            self.on_drag_accept(e, self.tab, self.fila, self.columna)
    
    # Método para actualizar la imagen del botón
    def actualizar_imagen(self, nueva_imagen_base64):
        self.imagen.src_base64 = nueva_imagen_base64
        self.imagen.update()  # Asegúrate de que se refleje en la interfaz

    # Método para actualizar el texto del botón
    def actualizar_texto(self, nuevo_texto):
        self.linea_texto.value = nuevo_texto
        self.linea_texto.update()  # Asegúrate de que se refleje en la interfaz

    def actualizar_posicion(self, nuevo_tab, nueva_fila, nueva_columna):
        self.tab = nuevo_tab
        self.fila = nueva_fila
        self.columna = nueva_columna

    def limpiar_boton(self):
        self.imagen.src_base64 = ""
        self.imagen.update()  # Asegúrate de que se refleje en la interfaz
        self.linea_texto.value = ""
        self.linea_texto.update()  # Asegúrate de que se refleje en la interfaz

    def guardar_imagen(self, ruta_imagen):
        with open(ruta_imagen, "rb") as image_file:
            foto_bytes = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')
            #foto_bytes = image_file.read()
        return foto_bytes

    #def leer_imagen(self, image_bytes):
    #    self.foto = self.guardar_imagen(image_bytes)
    #    self.page.add(ft.Image(src_base64=self.foto, width=80, height=80, fit=ft.ImageFit.COVER, border_radius=40))
    #    self.page.update()
    #    return image_bytes





# Ejemplo de uso
def main(page: ft.Page):
   
    def handle_click(e, tab, fila, columna):
        print(f"Botón clicado en Tab: {tab}, Fila: {fila}, Columna: {columna}")

    def handle_drag_will_accept(e, tab, fila, columna):
        print(f"Drag will accept en Tab: {tab}, Fila: {fila}, Columna: {columna}")

    def handle_drag_accept(e, tab, fila, columna):
        print(f"Drag accepted en Tab: {tab}, Fila: {fila}, Columna: {columna}")

    def guardar_imagen(self, ruta_imagen):
        with open(ruta_imagen, "rb") as image_file:
            foto_bytes = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')
            #foto_bytes = image_file.read()
        return foto_bytes

  
    # Crear el botón personalizado
    boton = BotonPersonalizado(
        posicion_tab=0,
        posicion_fila=1,
        posicion_columna=1,
        texto_boton="Mi Botón",
        foto="",  # Puedes pasar una imagen en base64 aquí
        on_click=handle_click,
        on_drag_will_accept=handle_drag_will_accept,
        on_drag_accept=handle_drag_accept,
        bgcolor="lightblue",  # Ejemplo de parámetro dinámico
        border_radius=10
    )

    # Dibujar el botón y agregarlo a la página de Flet
    page.add(boton.dibujar_boton())

    # Simulando una actualización posterior del botón
    boton.actualizar_texto("Nuevo Texto pùto")
    #page.update()
    #boton.actualizar_foto(guardar_imagen("assets/fondo.png"))  # Cambia a un string válido en base64

ft.app(target=main)

I'm very confused because I've been working for three days and I don't know why it isn't working as I need. I tried to push the new image in many ways, but I don't know if the image is not getting in the container or if I don't find the way to update it.
